# Eclipse git No more authentication methods available

Tags: eclipse

My Java project can pull code from ssh remote repository successful with command line and Intellij IDE. But after importing this project with Eclipse, I try pull code by Eclipse (Egit). I get error

[image]

this is ssh directory configuration on my computer

[image]

My Eclipse version is

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200
```

Egit version of my eclipse is
[image]

Comment: Does in _Window > Preferences: Team > Git_ switching the _SSH Client_ from _Apache MINA sshd_ to _JSch_ fix your issue (see also already fixed [Eclipse EGit bug 541793](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=541793))?

Comment: yes, i have tried follow  @howlger  instruction but still get error

Comment: Are your keys correctly registered with that server?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with EGit 5.5.1 (in _Help > Install New Software..._ work with the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates`](https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates))?

Comment: @howlger yes, EGit version i am using is 5.5.1

Comment: @nitind, i can pull success my git command line and Intellij so i think key is correct

Comment: The Eclipse Marketplace screenshot shows that there is version 5.5.1 available, but it does not show which version you have installed. When you click the _Installed_ button, you will get either an _Update_ or _Uninstall_ button. The question remains, can you reproduce this issue with EGit 5.5.1? By the way, Intellij just delegates to the command line whereas the Eclipse IDE has its own Git implementation (JGit) and does not require the command line Git.

Comment: eclipse show Installed.I try use eclipse pull code from another respository and it success. So i think this error happen because the remote git server